# HTM5 Canvas, suggestions for changing animation effect

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

So I'm new to canvas, and am still figuring out how things work. I am trying to make an animation of a volcano eruption. I separated the volcano and sky onto one layer, the eruption on the second layer, and the ash cloud on the third. I was referencing an example for the eruption animation, and in the way it is written, it blacks out the canvas. Is there a different way of achieving the same effect it already makes, but so that the opacity of the layer is all the way down so you can see the volcano and sky underneath the eruption? Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<style>
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
canvas {
 border: 1px solid black;;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="canvasesdiv" style="position:relative; width:400px; height:300px">
<canvas id="layer1" style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="layer2" style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="layer3" style="z-index: 3; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
<script>

//var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
//var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var layer1;
var layer2;
var layer3;
var particles;
var eruption;
var timer;
var timerRestart;

function init(){
layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
ctx1 = layer1.getContext("2d");
layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
ctx2 = layer2.getContext("2d");
canvas=layer3 = document.getElementById("layer3");
context=ctx3 = layer3.getContext("2d");

}

function animationHandler(){
fillBackgroundColor(canvas, context);
drawVolcano();
drawClouds();
eruption = setTimeout(makeParticles, 10);
}

function drawClouds(){

ctx3.beginPath();
ctx3.moveTo(0, 100);
ctx3.bezierCurveTo(0, 100, 75, 200, 150, 100);
ctx3.bezierCurveTo(150, 100, 225, 200, 300, 85);
ctx3.bezierCurveTo(300, 85, 375, 200, 450, 75);
ctx3.bezierCurveTo(450, 75, 525, 200, 600, 100);
ctx3.bezierCurveTo(600, 100, 700, 200, 800, 100);
ctx3.lineTo(800, 0);
ctx3.lineTo(0, 0);
ctx3.closePath();

ctx3.fillStyle = "#6f2a2a";
ctx3.fill();

ctx3.lineWidth = 5;
ctx3.strokeStyle = "#371515";
ctx3.stroke();

}

function drawVolcano(){

ctx1.beginPath();
ctx1.moveTo(0, 400);
ctx1.bezierCurveTo(0, 400, 250, 400, 325, 200);
ctx1.lineTo(425, 200);
ctx1.bezierCurveTo(425, 200, 450, 400, 800, 400);
ctx1.lineTo(800, 500);
ctx1.lineTo(0, 500);
ctx1.closePath();

ctx1.fillStyle = "#802b00";
ctx1.fill();

ctx1.lineWidth = 5;
ctx1.strokeStyle = "#b33c00";
ctx1.stroke();
}

function fillBackgroundColor(canvas, context){
ctx1.fillStyle = "#3399ff" ;
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function makeParticles() {
//create an array of particles for our animation
particles = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    particles.push(new Particle());
}

}

function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
 //converts from degrees to radians and returns
return (degrees * Math.PI)/180;
}

function Particle(){
 //the constructor for a single particle, with random starting x+y, velocity, color, and radius
 //this.x = Math.random()*canvas.width;
 //this.y = Math.random()*canvas.height;
this.x = canvas.width/2;
this.y = (0,0);
this.vx = Math.random()*16-8;
this.vy = Math.random()*10;
var colors = ["red", "#ff6600", "yellow", "#262626"];
this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
this.radius = 50;
}

function moveParticles() {
 //partially clear the screen to fade previous circles, and draw a new particle at each new coordinate
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx2.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
{
    var p = particles[i];
    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, degreesToRadians(360), true);
    ctx2.fillStyle = p.color;
    ctx2.fill();
    p.x += p.vx;
    p.y += p.vy;
    if(p.x < -50) p.x = canvas.width+50;
    if(p.y < -50) p.y = canvas.height+50;
    if(p.x > canvas.width+50) p.x = -50;
    if(p.y > canvas.height+50) p.y = -50;
    p.radius -= 1;
}

}


function clearScreen(color) {
 //clears the screen and fills with the color of choice
ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx2.fillStyle = color;
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}

window.onload = function() { 
init();
animationHandler();
timer = setInterval(moveParticles, 60);
//timerRestart = setInterval(makeParticles, 4000);
}

</script>
</html>
```

This is where the animation happens:

```
function moveParticles() {
 //partially clear the screen to fade previous circles, and draw a new particle at each new coordinate
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx2.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the previously drawn particles are "dimmed" by overwriting the entire canvas with a low-alpha fill. But, this also undesirably causes the underlying volcano to be "dimmed".

Instead of repeatedly "dimming" by filling the whole canvas with `rgba(0,0,0,0.3)`, you could reduce each individual particle's alpha with each new frame.

This can be done at the particle level by changing each particle's `rgba` fill.

Example:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var particle={
    // start with red base color
    // use a token (here @) which will be replaced with alpha
    baseColor:'rgba(255,0,0,@)',
    // start with the particle at full alpha
    // this alpha will be incrementally reduced 
    currentAlpha:1.00,
};

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(150,50,20,0,Math.PI*2);
    // change this particle's alpha    
    var fill=particle.baseColor.replace('@',particle.currentAlpha);
    particle.currentAlpha-=.01;
    if(particle.currentAlpha<=0){particle.currentAlpha=0;}
    ctx.fillStyle=fill;
    ctx.fill();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>A particle with reducing rgba alpha</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

For better performance, you could draw all particles with the same alpha value in a batch. This method would use `context.globalAlpha` to draw a batch of particles rather than changing each particle's `rgba`.

Comment: Okay, I definitely see what you're saying. I guess my next question is how would I change the alpha of each particle but still retain their color? The ways I've been trying has been making the particles turn solid black...

Comment: @intoitoverit. I've added a demo showing how to incrementally reduce a particle's alpha. Good luck with your project!

Comment: ctx.globalAlpha is very quick, I use it all the time with every call to render, and it has no effect on rendering performance and is certainly much quicker than invoking string replace, and if you are using gradients, patterns or images it is the only practical way to do any fading.